# How much $g$ can the wire be accelerated?

Tags: physics

> A wire can withstand the tension $T_{max} = M_{max}\cdot g$. If we
>   hang on an object with the mass of $m = \frac{M_{max}}{10}$ at the end of the
>   wire, how much $g$ can the wire be accelerated? ($g$ is gravitational force)

I've tried equate them

$T_{max} = M_{max}\cdot g = \frac{M_{max}}{10}$

and found the answer as $9g$. However, I'm not sure.

Regards!

Comment: would you mind sharing how you got that answer?

Comment: @TheIntegrator Is it correct? I don't know how I got that answer lol.

Comment: Well as gimusi said it depends on what the question is. I'm not that well versed in physics so im not the best person to ask.Maybe you could try [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: No, your answer is not correct, @Displayed.  If you show your work, we can show where your error arises.

Comment: @amWhy That's correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct....

Comment: It's correct that you note that it's correct that it's incorrect.  Note, gimusi does not answer 9g. You did.

Comment: @amWhy Oh sorry for that! :) Are you familiar with optics too? Perhaps I'd like to get your thinkings regarding to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that (neglecting the wire mass)

- initial tension: $T_0=mg=\frac{M_{max}}{10}g$
- increment in tension due to an up acceleration $a$: $\Delta T=ma=\frac{M_{max}}{10}a$

then the total tension in the wire is

$$T=T_0+\Delta T=\frac{M_{max}}{10}(g+a)$$

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: @Displayed You can check directly form the last equating $\frac{M_{max}}{10}(g+a)=M_{max}g$ and finding out $a$.

Comment: That was an olympiad question. I'm so excited to see the correct answer. So, am out of my mind right now.

Comment: Is it correct? :)

Comment: @Displayed If I have intepret the problem correctly by the givens, yes from $\frac{M_{max}}{10}(g+a)=M_{max}g$ we obtain easily $a=9g$. The only doubt is that if it is an olympiad question it seems too easy to solve. To be sure, do you have the original full text or the official solution?

Comment: I don't believe in myself! I really have 20 correct answers of 23! You're awesome now dont know what to write oh wait ! Sorry am so excited right now oh lol! You gave me the biggest prize! and yes I'd like to know the full solution.

Comment: @Displayed You are welcome! I'm happy if my hint has been useful! Bye

Comment: Also in particle physics or anything, does this seem correct $I_0 \frac{1-(v/c)^2}{1+(v/c)^2}$?

Comment: I had a conceptual question if you can reply.

Comment: @Displayed Of course if I can, what is the question?

Comment: In optics, if the refractive index of a medium is $4/3$, what would you say for rays? For example, you're at an aquarium and take a look at the window(with the refractive index of $4/3$ where fishes are located. What is the magnification?

Comment: @Displayed I should revise this topic. In case you can try to ask on Physics.SE! :)

Comment: Or imagine you have a capillary tube in a medium whose refractive index is $n = 2$. You notice that the radius of capillary tube is $1.50mm$ What is the real radius of capillary tube? The best answer seems to be $2.00mm$, right?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @Displayed I'm really sorry but at the moment i can't answer on this particular topic, I should revise the subject about optics. As suggested you coul ask for specific physics answer on Physics.SE! Bye

Comment: Just a reminder, gimusi, this user asked this trolling non-sense question yesterday:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765393/is-it-correct-to-say-a-g-sin-frac-alpha2.  Remember it?  Anyways, I guess no harm done in your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @amWhy Ops, is he the same! I didn't recognize him! at least this question seems to have more sense than the question made Yesterday. Cheers!

Comment: @gimusi The answer $9g$ is correct,right?